# Updating datagrid from SQL server - update process not working

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, data-binding, datagrid

I have a SQL server and I want to show it in the main form of my app.
I followed some guides and I succeeded in my attempt to link between the dataGrid and the SQL server table.

The problem is that when I want to update the datagrid and sync/reload the table from the SQL server again.

I have an event handler that calls a `updateDatadrid()` function each time I'm adding/editing rows in the database.

When I first start the app I'm calling this function and it's working, but after that if I'm calling it again with that handler I get some errors.

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control '' accessed from a thread
>   other than the thread it was created on.

Outside the function (global variables):

```
SqlConnection sConDataGrid; 
DataSet dbDataSet;
SqlDataAdapter da;
BindingSource dbBind;
string sqlCommand;

EDIT - I forgot to add :
DataGridView _dbView;
```

This is my code:

```
private void updateDataGrid()
{
        using (sConDataGrid = new SqlConnection("Data Source=" + SettingsForm.getAddress + ";Initial Catalog=" + SettingsForm.getDatabase + ";Integrated Security=False;User Id=" + SettingsForm.getUser + ";Password=" + SettingsForm.getPassword + ";Connect Timeout=0;"))
        {
            sConDataGrid.Open();
            sqlCommand = "select top 200 * FROM cstPackages order by _dateTime desc"; //reading the db from end to start   
            using (da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand, sConDataGrid))
            {
                da.Fill(dbDataSet, "cstPackages");
                    dbBind = new BindingSource(dbDataSet, "cstPackages");
                    _dbView.DataSource = dbBind;
                sConDataGrid.Close();
            }
        }
}
```

I tried to play with it, call only to the `da.Fill()` function from after the first time i called this function, but it didn't refresh the datagrid.
I tried to clear the dataset before I filled it again, but it made the program to crash.
I tried just to do `_dbView.Refresh()` but it didn't work as well..

**EDIT**
I don't understand, why if I make a button, and I put "click" event handler, and i'm calling my function from this event handler - it's working!
And if i'm calling to this function from the `SerialPort` `dataReceived` event handler - I get this error! what is the difference?
I thought maybe I created the event handler not in the proper way, so I just dragged a `SerialPort` control form the designer and double clicked on the event, the same happened.

I tried to make a timer, put it on enabled and at the end of the function call it to `stop()`, and in the serial received set it to `start()` but everything I do in the `SerialPort` handler is like "outside" the program. It doesn't start the timer.

Comment: I'm assuming _dbView is your DataGrid. Is that right? Have you tried _dbView.DataBind() after the line where you set the DataSource?

Comment: @Melanie - Yes this is my DatGrid, and I didn't try that before, but I checked not and there is no such a function :/

Comment: _Cross-thread operation not valid: Control '' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on._ What control and where this error occurs? Looks like you're trying to access something from different thread than that something was created. Probably dataGridView. The solution could be to access it via Invoke, but cannot tell you more unless you give more details about the error

Comment: When this error occurs this is the error I get, with ' '.
The debuger points on the `code` _dbView.DataSource = dbBind; `code` line. I have a "received" event handler that attached to a COM port, and when I get data to the COM port I'm adding/changing the database according to the string, and then I call this function again.

Comment: I think the problem is you created your DataGrid on your main thread.  But the event handling thread, that runs in reaction to a COM port event, is trying to modify the GUI.  Perhaps the event handling thread can send a message to the main thread to refresh the DataGrid.

Comment: Ok, that sounds logical but I have no experience with Threads.
I didn't even created any Thread by myself, all those Threads are a "side effect" of my programming probably.
How can I pass data between Threads then? I call this function from the even handler and it executes in its Thread :/

Comment: I googled and found this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(v=vs.80).aspx
"How to: Make Thread-Safe Calls to Windows Forms Controls"
They say I should use BackgroundWorker - So I did.
I created a BackgroundWorker and on the COM recieved handler I called to `BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync()` and from  `RunWorkerCompleted` event I called to my function, but it didn't help. the same happened here...

Comment: Please check the FAQ for how things work on Stack Overflow. If you've got an answer, post it *as* an answer, **don't** edit it into your question. Then, when you can, mark it as the answer that worked for you by clicking the check-mark next to it. That's how we know which answers are solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED**
After reading this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28VS.80%29.aspx
I tried using Invokes, and it worked!

```
new code:
        delegate void SetDataGridCallback();

        private void updateDataGrid()
        {
            if (this._dbView.InvokeRequired)
            {
                SetDataGridCallback d = new SetDataGridCallback(updateDataGrid);
                this.Invoke(d, new object[] {  });
            }
            else
            {
                using (sCon2 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=" + SettingsForm.getAddress + ";Initial Catalog=" + SettingsForm.getDatabase + ";Integrated Security=False;User Id=" + SettingsForm.getUser + ";Password=" + SettingsForm.getPassword + ";Connect Timeout=0;"))
                {
                    sCon2.Open();
                    string sqlCommand = "select top 200 * FROM cstPackages order by _dateTime desc"; //reading the db from end to start   
                    using (da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand, sCon2))
                    {
                        dbDataSet.Clear();
                        da.Fill(dbDataSet, "cstPackages");
                        BindingSource dbBind = new BindingSource(dbDataSet, "cstPackages");
                        _dbView.DataSource = dbBind;
                        _dbView.Refresh();
                         sCon2.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
     private void fill_grid()
    {

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "Your sql command ";

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@param", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = your_control.Text;

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = this.sqlConnection1;
        this.sqlConnection1.Open();


        SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adpt.Fill(ds);


        your_grid.DataSource = ds;


        this.sqlConnection1.Close();

        this.your_grid.DataBind();



    }
```

Then all you have to do is call this method whenever you need to "refresh" the grid.

Comment: Hey, I can't use `.DataBind();` . It doesn't show this function, and if I write it manually  - I get a compile error.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview_methods(v=vs.80).aspx
No such a method `DataBind()`

Comment: You have to add these two assembly references to your solution              System.Data and  
System.Data.SqlClient - Then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I think many reasons.
one  : your cache is not clear 
two : your computer work slowly
thd : your refresh is not really refresh. 
four : maybe it have time delay

first 
you do your "select sql" in database, make sure that you really commit
two 
you can write a backgroundword let your pragram time refresh . or make a button to refresh.
thd 
make your operate reopen.

Comment: I've been waiting a few minutes hoping it will update, but it didn't.
The database is rarely updating now (in my testings), I can control the COM port data frequency..

I want to void a background refresh of every x seconds because I think it's a wast of resources. I know exactly when the DB was changes so I know exactly when to update the DataGrid.